# HTML5 + Native camera access using <Input>

Tags: android, html, camera

I'm currently trying to access my Android 4.3 Samsung Galaxy Note's native camera through HTML5. I am using the following code

```
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"></input>
```

It works as it should except for one thing. When I click the input button to browse files, my camera does not appear on the list. I'm able to browse my image gallery and select an image but I can't select my camera and take a new picture. Is there any way to fix this?

thank you!

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I am also having this issue.